# Angular 5 Bootstrap Dialog, submitting requests multiple times

Tags: angular, angular5, ngx-bootstrap

Edit: It has been fixed. I just moved my subscribe code to the constructor and it worked like a charm.

I tried to make my Confirm Components dynamic, and built something like this. My ModalService:

```
    @Injectable()
    export class ModalService {
      bsModalRef: BsModalRef;
      constructor(private modalService: BsModalService) {}

      openModalWithComponent(title:string, message:string) {
        const initialState = {
          message:message,
          title:title,
          closeBtnName: 'Close'
        };
        debugger;
        this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(AlertComponent, {initialState});

     this.modalService.onHide.subscribe(()=>{
       console.log('the message is now: ', this.bsModalRef.content.message);
        });

      }
callback;
      openConfirmComponent(title:string, message:string, callback) {
    const initialState = {
      message:message,
      title:title,
      result:false
    };
    debugger;
    this.callback = callback;
    this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(ConfirmComponent, {initialState});
    var that  = this;
    this.modalService.onHide.subscribe(()=>{
        console.log('calling callback from confirm');
        callback(that.bsModalRef.content.result);
    });
  }
```

The confirm Component Code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BsModalService } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal/bs-modal-ref.service';

export interface ConfirmModel {
    title: string;
    message: string;

}

@Component({
    selector: 'confirm-component',
    templateUrl: '../views/ConfirmComponent.html'

})
export class ConfirmComponent implements ConfirmModel {
    title: string;
    message: string;
    result:boolean  = false;
  constructor(public bsModalRef: BsModalRef) {       
}
    confirm() {
        // on click on confirm button we set dialog result as true,
        // ten we can get dialog result from caller code
        this.result = true;
        this.bsModalRef.hide();

    }


    cancel() {
        this.result = false;
        this.bsModalRef.hide();
        this.bsModalRef.content.ok = false;
    }
}
```

The usage is like this:

```
this.dialogService.openConfirmComponent('Are you sure?', 'Would you like to save the selected shape?', function(result){
            if(result){
                console.log('emiting');
                that.SaveShape.emit();
            }
        });
```

Now what is happening is, when I click the Save button in my component, it calls that confirm component and if user presses Yes, then it emits the event. Now this line :

```
this.modalService.onHide.subscribe(()=>{
            console.log('calling callback from confirm');
            callback(that.bsModalRef.content.result);
        });
```

It subscribes the onhide event, and as soon as it hides, it fires the callback. The problem is, it is being subscribed multiple times. I click first time, it fires once. I click second time, it fires twice. How I can stop it from happening? I guess I need to unsubscribe somehow? I know this should be a pretty simple thing I am missing. Help?

Comment: never mind.. i figured what I was doing wrong.. I was subscribing it everytime the function is called... I should have only subscribe it once in the constructor. Fixed...

Answer (score 2):

```
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];

addRole() {
        this.addRoleRef = this.modalService.show(AddComponent, { backdrop: 'static' });
        this.subscriptions.push(
            this.modalService.onHide.subscribe((reason: string) => {
                this.getRoles();
                this.unsubscribe();
            })
        );
}

unsubscribe() {
        this.subscriptions[0].unsubscribe();
        this.subscriptions = [];
}
```

If we don't unsubscribe, the instance of modal service doesn't get cleared off. And so multiple requests are being called.

Try using the unsubscribe method, which helped me.
The more related example could also be found on site: https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals.

Comment: two problems here. 1: You should always explain why exactly this code will be helpful, or the mistakes I have done in my code. That is how generally the answers are accepted. 2: I have mentioned above that I figured out what I was doing wrong in comments. That being said, welcome to Stackoverflow :)